# Where is the missing Zend_Form_Element documentation?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

So the Zend_Form reference manual has a lot of information however it seems to me that a section on Zend_Form_Element types is missing.  The Zend_Form quickstart section (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html) lists each of the element types, however it doesn't give details on how to configure each type.  For example, what options can be passed to the textarea element type?

In the section titled "Creating Form Elements Using Zend_Form_Element" (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html), there are two references to 'the Standard Elements Chapter', however the hyperlinks just post back to themselves.

It sounds like the information is available somewhere and that the link is simply broken.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks...!

Comment: in the link that you posted, there is information about how to configure the form elements... in this link http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html you can see other examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite right, there seems to be a page missing from the online docs. Here's a mirror of the standard form elements page:

http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/zend.form.standardelements.html

this might be from an older version but there should be enough info there to help you.

Comment: Here's a slightly better formatted version from the previous ZF release: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.form.standardElements.html

Comment: Thanks Tim, nice one.  I tried to report this on by submitting an email under Contact at the Zend site, however the captcha is broken and won't accept my email!